# What is this graph called?

Tags: graph, reporting

I'm looking for a tool to help me graph some data. I have a set of processes running on a server, and these lov their start- and end times.

I want to be able to see how long each process ran for in relation to each other. The y-axis would show the names of these processes, the x-axis the time across a couple of days, and a plot would be drawn if process X was running from time A to time B.

I've made a mock up:[image]

Does this type of graph have a name? Is this available in Power BI? If not, what reporting tool would you recommend?

Comment: Check for Gantt-Chart.

Comment: @CostisAivalis thanks, that's it! Not all Gantt visuals allow for multiple durations at different times on a line, but I found one Power BI visual that suited my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [Gantt Chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart).

You can build a Gantt Chart with Power BI. Check the page [Building a Gantt Chart using Power BI](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/educator-developer-blog/building-a-gantt-chart-using-power-bi/ba-p/3605928).

You can also build it with MS Excel but this is somehow cumbersome: [How to make a Gantt chart in Excel](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/make-gantt-chart-excel/).